# Accessing controller inside overridden template-url of uib-tab

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap-tab

```
angular-bootstrap version used : 1.2.0
angular-version : 1.5.7
```

I am trying to override header html of `uib-tab` like below,

```
<li ng-class="{active: active, disabled: disabled}" class="uib-tab">
    <a ui-sref="MyController.overviewStateUrl" ng-click="select()" uib-tab-heading-transclude>{{heading}}</a>
</li>
```

When the page is rendered, the value for `ui-sref` is taken as `MyController.overviewStateUrl` instead of the real value which is stored in `overviewStateUrl` attribute of `MyController`. Is there any way to do it?

I tried to put it inside `interpolation`, but it returns empty string. [Here's](https://plnkr.co/edit/sgaJQAvC25CX3T6KiBv0?p=preview) the plunker.

Comment: `ui-sref` expects a string and doesn't evaluate an expression. If you want to pass an expression, then you should rightly interpolate them. If the interpolation returns an empty string, then check your controller

Comment: @Ladmerc, Since the directive uses isolated scope, `MyController` is not accessible inside that html. for example `<a ng-click="select()" uib-tab-heading-transclude>{{MyController.myHeader}}</a>` does not show `myHeader` value. I mean, it's not a problem of `ui-sref`, but i am not able to access the controller at all inside that html

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried as like below code?

```
<a ui-sref="{{MyController.overviewStateUrl}}" ng-click="select()" uib-tab-heading-transclude>{{heading}}</a>
```